Apply a tag using an AWS Lambda funtion to an S3 object with a space in it's name
I have a python function that I am running through a Lambda. The function runs properly when uploading an object to S3, if the object's name does not contain a space. For example if I upload an object called "example.txt" the object is tagged properly. However, if I upload an object called "example 2.txt" the function errors out with a permission denied error. Below is the python script I am running.
import json
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Log the event received
    logger.info(f"Received event: {json.dumps(event)}")

    try:
        # Iterate through each record in the event
        for record in event["Records"]:
            s3_bucket = record["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
            s3_key = record["s3"]["object"]["key"]
            
            # Log bucket and key information
            logger.info(f"Processing object {s3_key} in bucket {s3_bucket}")

            # Define the tag set
            tags = {
                "TagSet": [
                    {"Key": "SomeKey", "Value": "SomeValue"}
                ]
            }
            
            # Log the tags being applied
            logger.info(f"Applying tags to object: {tags}")

            try:
                # Add tags to the object
                response = s3.put_object_tagging(
                    Bucket=s3_bucket,
                    Key=s3_key,
                    Tagging=tags
                )

                # Log the request ID from the response metadata
                request_id = response.get('ResponseMetadata', {}).get('RequestId', 'N/A')
                logger.info(f"Successfully tagged object {s3_key} in bucket {s3_bucket} with tags: {tags}. S3 request ID: {request_id}")

            except ClientError as e:
                # Log any exceptions from the put_object_tagging call
                logger.error(f"Error tagging object {s3_key} in bucket {s3_bucket}: {e.response['Error']['Message']}")
                if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "AccessDenied":
                    logger.error("Access Denied. Check if the Lambda function's role has the necessary permissions.")
                # Optionally raise the exception if you want to stop processing further records
                raise

        # Return a success response
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps("S3 object tagged!")
        }

    except Exception as e:
        # Log any exceptions
        logger.error(f"Error processing event: {str(e)}")
        # Raise the exception to allow Lambda to handle it
        raise

I have verified my IAM role permissions and attempted to add an encoding library to the code, I have also attempted wrapping the s3_key in quotes.
The error I am getting when an object name contains a space is similar to
Operation: REST.PUT.OBJECT_TAGGING
Response Code: 403
Error Code: AccessDenied
Bucket: example
Key: example/example/example+2.txt

However, I do not receive this error if the object is titled example.txt

I've tried your code and works fine with me (having AdministratorAccess, that is). Try updating your IAM role and add Admin access to rule out out permission issue from the role. Does the examples came for two different buckets? If so, check if the buckets have additional bucket policy that prevent your lambda to access the object.

The example comes from the same bucket. Adding Admin access would likely solve the issue, but it's not really an option.
